# Custom UIFont for preferredFontForTextStyle

Tags: ios

How can I return a custom UIFont from `preferredFontForTextStyle` for each *Text style*?

e.g
I want to use ArialHebrew-Bold font for `UIFontTextStyleHeadline` and use ArialHebrew for `UIFontTextStyleBody`

Answer (score 41, accepted):

If you just like dynamic font-size with your own font you can do this

```
UIFontDescriptor *userFont = [UIFontDescriptor preferredFontDescriptorWithTextStyle:UIFontTextStyleBody];
float userFontSize = [userFont pointSize];
UIFont *font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"ArialHebrew-Bold" size:userFontSize];
```

Answer (score 9):

Swift's version:

```
let systemDynamicFontDescriptor = UIFontDescriptor.preferredFontDescriptor(withTextStyle: .body)
let size = systemDynamicFontDescriptor.pointSize
let font = UIFont(name: "ArialHebrew-Bold", size: size)
```

Answer (score 7):

Starting with iOS 11:

```
let bodyMetrics = UIFontMetrics(forTextStyle: .body)
let standardFont = ... // any font you want, for standard type size
let font = bodyMetrics.scaledFont(for: standardFont)
```